# Adding Timestamp to attribute table in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, spatial-database

I have the project where, in one part of it, I need to add the timestamp to uniform generated points along the line (road, in my project). There is a road and uniform distributed points on it, which represent the trajectory of a car. Each point represents the car's location at certain time on the road.

How can I add dynamic timestamp that if, let's say, I need to decrease the speed of the car, the timestamp of the certain point will change as well?

Comment: You've tagged this with `shapefile` which only supports day resolution in date fields.

Comment: You had a tag for PyQGIS but have not presented any code in your question body and so I have removed it.

Comment: Yo also have tags for [tag:shapefile] and [tag:spatial-database] but do not tell us which you are using.  If it's a spatial database then which type?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the QGIS field calculator you can create an expression on a `Time` type field, with the speed as a variable. Changing the speed and re-calculating the expression will adjust the times accordingly. For the example I used 14 m/s (approx 50 km/h) as the initial speed and 20:00 as an arbitrary start time, the points are 250 m apart (created with the [Points along Geometry](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#points-along-geometry) tool on a line. The tool automatically adds a `distance` column to the point layer).

Assuming distance is meters and speed is meters per second:

```sql
with_variable('speed', 14,                             -- set the speed variable
    with_variable('start_time', make_time(20, 0 ,0),   -- set a start time variable
        CASE 
            WHEN "distance" = 0                        
            THEN @start_time                           -- input the start time at zero distance
            
            ELSE @start_time + to_interval(to_string("distance" / @speed) || ' seconds')  -- add the elapsed interval (distance/speed) to the start time and calculate the remaining rows 
        END
    )
)
```

[image]

Change speed to 20 m/s:
[image]

Note: for the labels in the images, I removed the milliseconds component from the time.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!! But, by saying Time field type, do you mean Date?
Sorry for stupid questions, I just start working in QGIS :(

Comment: That's up to you :) QGIS offers both. I just chose time for the example. You can add the interval to a DateTime field and it will work the same.

Comment: In Field Calculator, there is no Time field type, sadly. There are only Whole number(integer), Whole number(integer 64 bit), Decimal number(real), String and Date. How can I add the field with Time field type? I tried the Date but it didn't work as I expected. Because, with the Date, the time difference can't be seen, since it shows only date as days, not seconds or minutes...

Comment: By the way, I use QGIS 3.22.2 version

Comment: You can use the `Add field` tool to add a `Time` (or `DateTime`) field.

Comment: Thank you so much! I dealt with it. I couldn't see Time field before, because I chose a problematic or inaccurate CRS type. After changing it, everything started to make sense eventually :)

Comment: Good to hear :)